# Ceph Octopus zabbix config-show fails with python error

Tags: python, ceph

Hi I have managed to install Ceph Octopus 15.2.4 and python Python 3.6.8 on CentOS Linux release 8.2.2004.

Cluster health is Good. However, when I try configure the zabbix module using steps in this
https://docs.ceph.com/en/latest/mgr/zabbix/

I get

```
Error EINVAL: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/ceph/mgr/mgr_module.py", line 1167, in _handle_command
    return self.handle_command(inbuf, cmd)
  File "/usr/share/ceph/mgr/zabbix/module.py", line 407, in handle_command
    return 0, json.dumps(self.config, index=4, sort_keys=True), ''
  File "/lib64/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 238, in dumps
    **kw).encode(obj)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'index'
```

I checked the template and it looks to be latest.

Not sure what seems to be the issue here.

Regards,
j

Comment: Interestingly, it does send data to zabbix!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is typo bug.

https://github.com/ceph/ceph/commit/0e9303d0599c92e575aae7acca87328ed8ee9527

This one has a bad typo in it! It should be "indent=4", not "index=4"!

But, this problem is not fixed in 15.2.5.

Comment: Thank you so much. I changed the "/usr/share/ceph/mgr/zabbix/module.py" line 407, from index to Indent. Then I restarted the ceph-mgr Service. Now config-show works.